# Need explanation of error message 'TypeError: Receiver must be an instance of class'

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, typeerror, ecmascript-next

When I run this code:

```
'use strict';

class Base {
  constructor() {
    this._public();
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  _public() {
    this.#privateMethod();
  }

  #privateMethod() {
    this.bar = 1234;
  }
}

const c = new Child();
console.log(c.bar);
```

I get the following error:

```
   this.#privateMethod();
         ^

TypeError: Receiver must be an instance of class Child
```

As I understand JavaScript, the receiver in the following code is exactly an instance of the class Child. It's even shown in the dev tools inspector:

[image: dev-tools screenshot]

**So could someone please explain to me what's going on? Is it a bug or what?**

---

Actually FF shows a more accurate error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access private field or method: object is not the right class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one example of why it's best not to call public instance methods from constructors. When your `Base` class constructor calls `this._public()`, `Child`'s initialization is not (yet) complete. The earliest you can use `Child` members is **after** `super()` has returned, not before. It's only after `super()` returns that `Child`'s automatic initialization (such as setting up private fields and methods, and initializing public properties defined via class fields syntax) is complete. You can see this with public class fields as well:

```js
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log("test" in this); // false
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    test; // <== Public class field
    
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("test" in this); // true
    }
}

new Child();
```

You're okay to call `this._public()` from `Child`'s constructor just after `super()` returns (although, again, it's best not to call public methods from constructors! better to call `#privateMethod` directly), because `Child` will be fully ready by then (other than any initialization you're doing in its constructor, of course), but not *before* `super()` returns.

Comment: Thank you, sadly, this topic was not present in your book, 'The new toys'. I re-read pieces from it twice a month.

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov - Drat!! :-) Sorry. But hopefully it was useful in other respects.

Comment: the crucial point, as I understood, is that the private members `#foo` are present on the instance itself, not in the prototype chain. That's why they are not accessible in the constructors. When I spelt that (where the private members are present), it looked so obvious, that I'm ashamed

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov - FWIW, IMHO, absolutely **no** cause for shame. But you're right, private members aren't on the prototype, and you're spot-on that that's part of what matters here. Happy coding!